# how to frame independent claim for comparing two components of a system

Tags: claim-construction, independent

(Its a sample) Input: A play toy. that has different set of balls. each set has same color of balls. color of balls of one set is different from color of ball of another set. Kindly correct and suggest me appropriate claim frame. Here I framed an independent claim "A play toy comprising a plurality of ball sets, wherein each of the plurality of ball sets comprising a plurality of ball members, a plurality of ball members of a ball set of the plurality of ball sets has same color value but is of different color value from the color value of a plurality of ball members of another ball set of the plurality of ball sets;"please correct me

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me. As long as it is clear what you mean, you should do fine. And clarity is quite subjective, so depending on the examiner your claim may be clear or not. A proposal in case it may be of help:

A play toy comprising a plurality of ball sets, wherein each ball set of the plurality of ball sets comprises a plurality of ball members having a same color value and the color value being different from the color value of the ball members of remaining ball sets of the plurality of ball sets.